# mysql_query segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#define IP 20
#define USER 20
#define PD 20
#define DB 20
//set configuration
struct configuration
{
    char* ip;
    int port;
    char* user;
    char* password;
    char* dbname;
};
struct configuration  getconf(const char*,const char*);

int main()
{
    //mysql
    struct configuration str_mysql;
    str_mysql=getconf("conf.txt","MYSQL");
    MYSQL *conn_mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *res_ptr;
    MYSQL_ROW sqlrow;
    conn_mysql=mysql_init(NULL);
    if(!conn_mysql)
    {
            printf("mysql_init failed\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //printf("%s %d %s %s %s\n",str_mysql.ip,str_mysql.port,str_mysql.user,str_mysql.password,str_mysql.dbname);
    conn_mysql = mysql_real_connect(conn_mysql,str_mysql.ip,str_mysql.user,str_mysql.password,str_mysql.dbname,3306,NULL,0);
    if(conn_mysql)
    {
            printf("Connection success\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Connection failed\n");
            if(mysql_error(conn_mysql))
            {
                    printf("Connection error %d: %s\n",mysql_errno(conn_mysql),mysql_error(conn_mysql));
            }
    }
    printf("this doesn't work!!!");
    res=mysql_query(conn_mysql,"use leke_entiredb;");
    res = mysql_query(conn_mysql,"SELECT * from teacher;");
    printf("222");
```

I'm trying to execute mysql query using the function mysql_query, however I get a segmentation fault. And the func printf doesn't work until I delete the func mysql_query. Any ideas?
tips: I try selecting data using mysql client, it works without problems.

Comment: You do know that `printf` is writing to `stdout`? And that `stdout` by default is *line buffered*? Meaning the buffer is flushed and the output actually written when you print a newline. That's why you should have trailing newlines in output, and you have no newline at all in your two last shown `printf` calls.

Comment: Also, you should make a debug-build of your program and run in a debugger to catch the crash when it happens. That way you can easily locate where in your source it really happens, and also examine involved variables to validate their values. If nothing else, please edit your question to show us the *exact* location of the crash as well as the values of all involved variables. I also recommend you read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The first thing you do if you get a segmentation fault is pop open the debugger. It's anyone's guess as to why this malfunctioned because we don't have a running copy of your code. My guess is a buffer overflow somewhere, or a NULL pointer you forgot to initialize. That configuration code is not shown and could be problematic.

Comment: thank you. I have found the problem.That I got an NULL pointer near the query.